# ASP.net form Double Entry

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, forms

I have a form that I need the user to be able to type something in a `textbox`, after they tab out have them enter the same value in another `textbox` in proximity to it to assure they entered it incorrectly. After that, the second `textbox` is to disappear and they will continue to the next field without ever having a `postback`.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this most efficiently? Is there a control that will facilitate this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by javascript easily. on the onblur or onchange clientside events you should check two textbox's values.

An alternative option : maybe you want to use [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(VS.71).aspx) to compare values of your form elements. Don't forget to set EnableClientScript=true and use [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9h59855(VS.80).aspx) control.